# How to expand the limit of screen mouse access for FPS side rotation

Tags: rotation, godot, screen

I started coding in Godot and i have a working FPS controller but the problem is that when i move my mouse sideways , it cannot move my sight beyinid that side of my screen , in other words the movement of my charecter is limited by the size of my screen , how to prevent this

Rotation code

```
func _input(event):
if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
    head.rotate_y(deg2rad(event.relative.x * -mouseSensitivity))
    camera.rotate_x(deg2rad(event.relative.y * -mouseSensitivity))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That you want is to capture the mouse pointer.

Call [`input.set_mouse_mode`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-set-mouse-mode) it takes as parameter a [`MouseMode`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#enum-input-mousemode).

Copied from the linked documentation:

> enum MouseMode:

> **MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE = 0** --- Makes the mouse cursor visible if it is hidden.
> **MOUSE_MODE_HIDDEN = 1** --- Makes the mouse cursor hidden if it is visible.
> **MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED = 2** --- Captures the mouse. The mouse will be hidden and its position locked at the center of the screen.
>
> Note: If you want to process the mouse's movement in this mode, you need to use InputEventMouseMotion.relative.
>
> **MOUSE_MODE_CONFINED = 3** --- Makes the mouse cursor visible but confines it to the game window.

`MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE` and `MOUSE_MODE_HIDDEN` let the mouse pointer, visible or hidden. `MOUSE_MODE_CONFINED` limits the movement of the mouse pointer to the window, that means it gets stuck at the edge, and we do not want that. However, with `MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED` it will register relative movement, but the mouse pointer remains at the center (which also means that anything that relies on the position of the pointer won't work).

Example:

```
func _ready():
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED);
```

With the mouse pointer captured, your camera script should work.

---

And you encounter a couple problems:

1. You can't use the mouse to close the game window.
2. Any UI won't work.

That means you are going to need a way to change the `MouseMode` to `MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE`. You could, for example use an input action:

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("ui_cancel"):
        Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE);
```

You can imagine that would also include code that open the in-game menu with the option to close the game among other things (e.g. set the mouse sensitivity). *Or if the game is windowed, you can just close the window.* Then, when the menu is closed, you would then set `MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED` again for the camera to continue to work.

---

You probably want to pause the game while the menu is open. You can use `get_tree().paused = true;` for that. *Set to `false` to un-pause, of course. Remember to set the [pause_mode](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/pausing_games.html) of your nodes appropriately. You may also be interested in using `Engine.time_scale = 0.0;` (which would also stop animated shaders).

---

On the flip side, if you don't have a menu to show at all, you probably want to recapture the mouse when the user clicks on the window. In that case, handle the click input as you normally would, and check `Input.get_mouse_mode() == Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE`, if that is the case, capture the mouse pointer. You may want to call `get_tree().set_input_as_handled()` if you want to avoid that click event being handled by some other script afterwards.

---

I suppose there is another way to go about this, and that is to move the mouse pointer.

To do that, you can call [`get_viewport().warp_mouse(Vector2 to_position)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_viewport.html#class-viewport-method-warp-mouse) or [`Input.warp_mouse_position(Vector2 to)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-warp-mouse-position). *In my tests these do the same thing.*

These would also trigger an input event. They are different in that`event.relative` will be `(0, 0)` for these events. Which is not much trouble for you.

With that, I present to you, poor man's mouse capture:

```
func _process(_delta):
    var viewport = get_viewport();
    viewport.warp_mouse(viewport.size * 0.5);
```

You probably want to set a variable to decide if you want to capture or not, and set an input action to change it… Yeah, the stuff I explained above. I'd recommend do it with `set_mouse_mode`, however, many recommend to write your own code to keep the mouse pointer centered (a solution for game development frameworks that do not have this built in) that probably people would suggest it if I don't mention it. *It may also lead people searching for "how to return the mouse to the center of the screen in Godot?" to `set_mouse_mode`, which is what they probably need.*

Comment: i actually did figure out this but you got it....great , tnx